# Transcription - strands, directions

Tags: genetics

I am hoping that you can help me improve my understanding of transcription. :)  I have tried searching for the answers to all of these questions online already, but I have either had trouble finding relevant information or I have had trouble understanding it (i.e. it was too high-level for me).  I have also tried to answer my questions by browsing through different maps of genes (like this one: http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hg38&lastVirtModeType=default&lastVirtModeExtraState=&virtModeType=default&virtMode=0&nonVirtPosition=&position=chr9%3A132847932-133136551&hgsid=709471277_W3A9vdobj2J7obkSXshDnCBnaTeK), but my questions are still unresolved.  Please note that I have come up with the following questions in my independent learning - these questions are NOT assigned homework.  In all questions, I'm referring to eukaryotic (linear) DNA.

1. Am I correct to believe that in a single chromosome, one strand of DNA is **not** the template strand for **all** genes within that chromosome?  For instance, let's call one ssDNA molecule "A" and the complementary ssDNA molecule "B"; together, A and B make up a single chromosome.  Am I correct to believe that in a single chromosome, the template strand for some genes will be A, and for other genes will be B?
2. If my statement in question #1 is correct, then does that mean that multiple genes within a chromosome can be transcribed in opposite directions?  Note that when I say direction, I do NOT mean 5' to 3' vs 3' to 5'.  What I mean by "direction" is looking from left to right.
3. Is it true that both strands of the double helix **cannot** be transcribed for a single gene in question?  Is this because the promoter will only be found on one of the strands?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: I think the fourth question ought to be separate; the question block is supposed to be for only one question, but I *think* the first 3 are related closely enough that they could be addressed in a single answer which deals with the underlying principle.

Comment: @rotaredom thank you for your feedback!  I removed the 4th question.

Comment: I have answered questions 1 and 2  [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56440/why-are-there-six-reading-frames-if-only-one-strand-of-dna-is-referred-to-as-the) and [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/71530/what-direction-is-a-sequence-in-databases-written). Your answer to your third question is right in principle, but there are cases of overlapping transcripts (promoters on different strands) as I mention [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/79876/strand-representation-in-the-dna-version-of-the-genetic-code/79883#79883) and you can find elsewhere.

Comment: These questions have been answered many times now. I think the closest (also with respect to the question title and body) would be, IMO, [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/69914/3340).