# How to determine which is the nucleotide sequence of a gene?

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequencing, blast, ncbi

I have came across a few  genes that show different nucleotide sequence in different databases. I then found out that the sequences are actually reverse complement of each other. How do i determine which is the actual nucleotide sequence of a gene,and not the reverse complement version of it?

Comment: Usually the reported sequence for a mRNA in NCBI is the sense strand. Can you give an example of a gene whose sequence you are unsure of?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What direction is a sequence in databases written?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/71530/what-direction-is-a-sequence-in-databases-written)

Comment: Hi @WYSIWYG below are the nucleotide sequences of the rplC gene. The first one is from NCBI, while the second I received from a sequencing company for my strain:

>ATCC 19977 R rplC ncbi
CTACTTCTCACCTCGCTTGACAGCGGTGCGGACCACAACCAAGCCACCCTTACGTCCGGGGATGGCACCC
TTGATCAGCAGTACGCCGTTCTCGGCATCGACCTTGTGCACCACCAGGTTCTGAGTGGTGACGCGATCGC
TACCCATACGTCCGGACATCCGGGTGC
>M61 S
ATGGCAAGAAAAGGAATTCTGGGCACCAAGCTGGGTATGACGCAGGTGTTCGACGACAAC
AACCGGGTTGTCCCGGTAACCGTCGTCAAGGCCGGCCCCAATGTGGTGACCCGCATCCGG
ACCACCGAGCAGGACGGCTACAGCGCCGTGCAGCTCGCGTATGGCGAGATCAGCCCCCGC
AAGGTGACCAAGCCGGTCACCGGTCAGTTCGCCGCCGCGGGC

Comment: It's really important for me to know the exact sequence, as i am looking for a nucleotide change at a specific location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run a blast of your sequence. Then explore the results and you'll see somewhere that says "strand"  and is indication whether is plus/minus.

https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi

Also blast has a graphical interface in which you'll clearly see the matching and non-matching bases. Therefore it should help you to identify the differences between the 2 sequences.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you look up a transcript sequence it will be in the correct orientation.  If you look up a gene based on genomic coordinates, it may not be.

We can't tell you why your first sequence is in the wrong orientation from what you pasted.